# DATEDIFF by User ID

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was wondering if there was a way to calculate `datediff()` by a user ID. For example, I have:

```
SELECT USER_ID, DATE, ?*
FROM TABLE_1
WHERE DATE BETWEEN 2018-01-01 AND 2018-01-31
```

Would pull:

```
USER_ID     DATE          DATEDIFF
001         2018-01-01    -
001         2018-01-05    5
002         2018-01-02    -
003         2018-01-03
003         2018-01-05    2
```

*The query in question is if there's a way to just calculate the difference between 2 dates grouped by user_id if there are 2 or more `User_ID`'s that are the same.

Comment: Sure take a look at LAG. Also, keep in mind the DATEDIFF requires a date part that you are interested in, in your case I assume it is DAY. If you need more detailed help you need to provide us with more details. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Use `LAG()` function

Comment: LAG() seems interesting. I've never used it before. Doing some reading on it now. But, for some reason it's just getting me the previous date, instead of like you said the number of days.

Comment: Never mind, just got it to work with the datediff - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see where the 5 comes from.  I think it should be 4.

You can do:

```
select user_id, date,
       datediff(day, lag(date) over (partition by user_id order by date), date) as diff
from t;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use LAG() or the more scaleable way:

```
DECLARE @user TABLE
(
    UserId INT,
    DateColumn DATE
)

INSERT @user VALUES (1, '2018/06/30');
INSERT @user VALUES (1, '2018/06/30'); 
INSERT @user VALUES (2, '2018/06/30');
INSERT @user VALUES (3, '2018/06/30');
INSERT @user VALUES (3, '2018/07/01'); 
INSERT @user VALUES (3, '2018/07/02');


SELECT UserId, DateColumn, DATEDIFF(DAY, MinDate, MaxDate) AS Diff
FROM (
    SELECT UserId, DateColumn, MIN(DateColumn) OVER(PARTITION BY UserId) AS MinDate, MAX(DateColumn) OVER(PARTITION BY UserId) AS MaxDate
    FROM @user
) AS sub
```

Comment: This doesn't return the data like they claim they want. It shows NULL for the first date. But it isn't very clear what they want. You really should use ANSI standard date format of YYYYMMDD. Being that I am in the US I have to the dateformat on my session or your date strings are invalid.

Comment: @SeanLange Thanks for the info with the date format. The claim is unclear anyway. Whats about 3 users? Which difference is the correct? My solution is only a template to reach the goal.

Comment: Yes I totally agree the question is not really clear.

Comment: Sorry about not clarifying the question. But yeah the datediff, lag, and partition totally did the trick. I was just looking for if the difference in days between each users visit. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You appears to want `lag()` :

```
select *, datediff(dd, prev, dt) as dtdiff
from (select *, lag(dt) over (partition by id order by dt) prevdt
      from table
     ) t;
```